Proof of Batalin-Fradkin-Vilkovisky (BFV) theorem using BRST operator and graded Poisson bracket algebra
In the proof of Batalin-Fradkin-Vilkovisky (BFV) theorem one has to determine how the path integral measure changes. The set of canonical variables
$$\varphi = (Q^A;P_{A}) =(q,\eta;\pi,\mathscr{P})\tag{10}$$
changes under the BRST transformation as
$$\varphi\to\tilde{\varphi}=\varphi+\{\varphi,\Omega\}\mu \tag{10}$$
where $q$ and $\pi$ are the ordinary phase space coordinate and momenta (bosonic) and $\eta$ and $\mathscr{P}$ are fermionic ghost fields and their momenta, $\Omega$ is the BRST charge and $\mu$ is an arbitrary fermionic parameter. The Poisson bracket is graded, that is,
$$\{F,G\} = \frac{\partial_{r}F}{\partial Q^A} \frac{\partial_{l}G}{\partial P_A} - (-1)^{|F||G|} \frac{\partial_{r}G}{\partial Q^A} \frac{\partial_{l}F}{\partial P_A}\tag{1}$$
where we have used left and right derivatives and $|F|,|G|$ are $0,1$ is these are bosonic or fermionic respectively. Then the paper claims that the integration measure changes by the following Jacobian factor
$${\rm d}\varphi={\rm d}\tilde{\varphi}(1+\{\mu,\Omega\})\tag{15}$$
My question by and large is how to consistently prove this. Below I show my attempt and the concerns and confusions.
Attempt:
$$\begin{align} {\rm d}\tilde{\varphi} & = \det\left(\frac{\partial \tilde{\varphi}}{\partial \varphi}\right) {\rm d} \varphi \qquad (\text{step 1})\\
& = \det\left( 1 + \frac{\partial_{l}}{\partial \varphi}(\{\varphi,\Omega\}\mu)\right) {\rm d} \varphi \qquad (\text{step 2})\\
& \approx \left( 1 + {\rm tr}\frac{\partial_{l}}{\partial \varphi}(\{\varphi,\Omega\}\mu)\right) {\rm d} \varphi \qquad (\text{step 3})\\
& = \left( 1 + \frac{\partial_{l}}{\partial Q^A}(\{Q^A,\Omega\}\mu) + \frac{\partial_{l}}{\partial P_A}(\{P_A,\Omega\}\mu)\right) {\rm d} \varphi \qquad (\text{step 4})\\
& = \left( 1 + \frac{\partial_{l}}{\partial Q^A}\left(\frac{\partial_{l}\Omega}{\partial P_{A}}\mu \right) + \frac{\partial_{l}}{\partial P_A}\left(-(-1)^{|P_{A}||\Omega|}\frac{\partial_{r}\Omega}{\partial Q^A}\mu\right)\right) {\rm d} \varphi \qquad (\text{step 5})\\
& = \left( 1 + \frac{\partial^2_l\Omega}{\partial Q^A \partial P_{A}}\mu + (-1)^{(|\Omega|+|P_{A}|)|Q^A|} \frac{\partial_l\Omega}{\partial P_A} \frac{\partial_l \mu}{\partial Q^A} -(-1)^{|P_{A}||\Omega|}\left(\frac{\partial_{l}\partial_{r}\Omega}{\partial P_{A}\partial Q^A}\mu + (-1)^{(|\Omega|+|Q^A|)|P_{A}|} \frac{\partial_{r}\Omega}{\partial Q^A}\frac{\partial_{l}\mu}{\partial P_A}\right)\right) {\rm d} \varphi \qquad (\text{step 6})\\
\end{align}$$
Now let's focus on the second and fourth terms in the step 6.
$$\left(\frac{\partial^2_{l}\Omega}{\partial Q^A P_A} - (-1)^{|P_A||\Omega|}\frac{\partial_l\partial_r\Omega}{\partial P_A \partial Q^A}\right)\mu$$

For a bosonic set of variables $(Q^A,P_B)$ left and right derivatives are the same and the above term vanishes as the partial derivatives commute.
For a fermionic set of variables $(Q^A,P_B)$ left and right derivatives of a fermionic object $\Omega$ are the same and the above term vanishes as the partial derivatives of fermionic objects anti-commute.

$$\begin{align} {\rm d}\tilde{\varphi} & = \left( 1 + (-1)^{(|\Omega|+|P_{A}|)|Q^A|} \frac{\partial_l\Omega}{\partial P_A} \frac{\partial_l \mu}{\partial Q^A} - (-1)^{(|\Omega|+|Q^A|)|P_{A}|+|P_{A}||\Omega|} \frac{\partial_{r}\Omega}{\partial Q^A}\frac{\partial_{l}\mu}{\partial P_A}\right) {\rm d} \varphi \qquad (\text{step 7})\\
\end{align}$$
The second and the third becomes
For $(Q^A,P_A)$ bosonic (the following identity is for only one pair and not summed over $A$),
$$\begin{align} & \left( \frac{\partial_l\Omega}{\partial P_A} \frac{\partial_l \mu}{\partial Q^A} - \frac{\partial_{r}\Omega}{\partial Q^A}\frac{\partial_{l}\mu}{\partial P_A}\right) \qquad (\text{step 7})\\
& = \left( - \left(  \frac{\partial_r \mu}{\partial Q^A}\frac{\partial_l\Omega}{\partial P_A} + \frac{\partial_{r}\Omega}{\partial Q^A}\frac{\partial_{l}\mu}{\partial P_A}\right)\right) \qquad (\text{step 8})
\end{align}$$
For $(Q^A,P_A)$ fermionic (the following identity is for only one pair and not summed over $A$),
$$\begin{align} & \left( \frac{\partial_l\Omega}{\partial P_A} \frac{\partial_l \mu}{\partial Q^A} + \frac{\partial_{r}\Omega}{\partial Q^A}\frac{\partial_{l}\mu}{\partial P_A}\right) \qquad (\text{step 9})\\
& = \left(  \frac{\partial_r \mu}{\partial Q^A}\frac{\partial_l\Omega}{\partial P_A} + \frac{\partial_{r}\Omega}{\partial Q^A}\frac{\partial_{l}\mu}{\partial P_A}\right) \qquad (\text{step 10})
\end{align}$$
Then we have
$${\rm d}\tilde{\varphi} = \left(1 - \{\mu,\Omega\}_{\rm bosonic} + \{\mu,\Omega\}_{\rm fermionic}\right) {\rm d}\varphi$$
Or equivalently
$${\rm d}\varphi = \left(1 + \{\mu,\Omega\}_{\rm bosonic} - \{\mu,\Omega\}_{\rm fermionic}\right) {\rm d}\tilde{\varphi}$$
assuming small $\mu$.
Questions:

Step 1: Is the Jacobian identity always valid? As we are dealing with fermionic variables.

Step 2: Should we take left or right derivative here?

Step 5: I have assumed that the quantity $\frac{\partial A}{\partial B}$ has parity $|A|+|B|$. Is this correct?

Step 8 and 10: Because $\mu$ and $\Omega$ are both fermionic the Poisson bracket is defined without the usual minus sign between the two terms?

Does the paper by $\{\mu,\Omega\}$ on the full phase space variables mean $\{\mu,\Omega\}_{\rm bosonic} - \{\mu,\Omega\}_{\rm fermionic}$ where there's a relative sign difference between bosonic and fermionic sectors of the variables. Is this because for the Grassmann variables the variable change requires inverse of the Jacobian?



OP's calculation looks overall correct, except perhaps for the notion of the superdeterminant/Berezinian and supertrace. For comparison and clarity, let us provide a complete calculation, which hopefully answers OP's questions.

Rewrite the equal-time (ET) super-Poisson bracket as
$$\begin{align} \{F(t),G(t)\}~=~&\frac{\partial_R F(t)}{\partial \varphi^I(t)} \{\varphi^I(t),\varphi^J(t)\} \frac{\partial_L G(t)}{\partial \varphi^J(t)}\cr~=~&-(-1)^{|F||G|}\{G(t),F(t)\},\end{align}\tag{1}$$
where the Poisson matrix
$$  \{\varphi^I(t),\varphi^J(t)\}~=~-(-1)^{|I||J|}\{\varphi^J(t),\varphi^I(t)\} $$
in canonical/Darboux coordinates is independent of the phase space variables
$$\varphi^I~=~(Q^A;P_A)~=~ (q,\eta;\pi,\mathscr{P}).\tag{10}$$
The super-Poisson bracket satisfies a super Jacobi identity.

Here $|I|$ is the Grassmann parity of $\varphi^I$. The left and right derivatives are related as
$$ \frac{\partial_R F}{\partial \varphi^I}~=~(-1)^{(|F|+1)|I|}\frac{\partial_L F}{\partial \varphi^I}$$
with overall Grassmann parity $|F|+|I|.$

Let us now infinitesimally change integration variables
$$\begin{align} \tilde{\varphi}^I(t)-\varphi^I(t)~=~&\delta\varphi^I(t)~=~\{\varphi^I(t),\Omega(t)\}\mu\cr
 ~=~& \{\varphi^I(t),\varphi^J(t)\} \frac{\partial_L \Omega(t)}{\partial \varphi^J(t)}\mu\end{align}\tag{10}$$
in the path integral, where
$$ \mu~=~\int\! dt ~\delta\Psi\tag{14} $$
is Grassmann-odd. Here $\Omega(t)$ is the classical Grassmann-odd BRST charge,
$$\{\Omega(t),\Omega(t)\}~=~0.\tag{11} $$

Then the path integral measure transforms with a Jacobian
$$ d\tilde{\varphi}~=~Jd\varphi, \tag{15}$$
where
$$\begin{align}J-1~=~&{\rm sDet}\left(\frac{\delta_R\tilde{\varphi}^J(t^{\prime})}{\delta\varphi^I(t)}\right) -1\cr
~=~&{\rm sDet}\left(\frac{\delta_L\tilde{\varphi}^J(t^{\prime})}{\delta\varphi^I(t)}\right) -1\cr
~=~&{\rm sTr}\left(\frac{\delta_L}{\delta\varphi^I(t)} \delta\varphi^J(t^{\prime})\right)\cr
~=~&\int\! dt (-1)^{|I|}\frac{\delta_L}{\delta\varphi^I(t)} \delta\varphi^I(t)\cr
~=~&\int\! dt (-1)^{|I|}\frac{\delta_L}{\delta\varphi^I(t)} \left(\{\varphi^I(t),\varphi^J(t)\} \frac{\partial_L \Omega(t)}{\partial \varphi^J(t)}\mu \right)\cr
~=~&-\int\! dt \{\varphi^J(t),\varphi^I(t)\}  \left(\frac{\delta_L}{\delta\varphi^I(t)}\frac{\partial_L \Omega(t)}{\partial \varphi^J(t)}\right)\mu \cr
&-\int\! dt \frac{\delta_L\mu}{\delta\varphi^I(t)}\{\varphi^I(t),\varphi^J(t)\} \frac{\partial_L \Omega(t)}{\partial \varphi^J(t)}\cr
~=~&-\int\! dt \{\varphi^J(t),\varphi^I(t)\} \delta(t\!-\!t) \left(\frac{\partial_L}{\partial\varphi^I(t)}\frac{\partial_L \Omega(t)}{\partial\varphi^J(t)}\right)\mu \cr
&-\int\! dt \left(\frac{\partial_L}{\partial\varphi^I(t)}\delta\Psi(t)\right)\{\varphi^I(t),\Omega(t)\}\cr
~=~&0-\int\! dt \{\delta\Psi(t),\Omega(t)\}.
\end{align}\tag{15}$$
In the last equality, we used a superversion of Liouville's theorem: Hamiltonian vector fields are divergencefree, cf. the $I\leftrightarrow J$ symmetry. Also we have assumed that the Dirac delta function $\delta(0)$ is appropriately regularized. In the second equality, we used that
$$ {\rm sDet}(A)~=~{\rm sDet}(A^T). $$


References:

I.A. Batalin & G.A. Vilkovisky, Phys. Lett. B69 (1977) 309.

Bryce DeWitt, Supermanifolds, Cambridge Univ. Press, 1992.



It's great that you've provided a complete proof with a consistent notation. However, as I am not familiar with the manipulations containing super-Jacobian/-determinant/-trace etc., I'll have to go through this again and again carefully. But as you mention my overall proof looks correct. So can you please comment on my question number 4 & 5? My other question I think has been answered. More, inside sDet left derivative can be changed to right derivative? The second order derivative of BRST charge being zero, is my reasoning alright? Similar reasoning also applies in your expression
